# Check if my Nodejs server is running remotely

Tags: node.js

I have a Nodejs server running a website remotely in a Windows 10 machine. But the machine is sometimes turned off and I do not know that the website is down.

I was thinking of creating a Nodejs website and have it run in Heroku that sends a request to my website running in the windows machine every 5 minutes and notify me via email if it does not get a response. However, I wanted to know if there are better options available for situations like these.

Comment: If what you want to know is whether your web site is responding, then the best way to monitor that is to create some outside agent that pings it every once in awhile to see if it's actually up and running.  That's the best type of end-to-end test there is.

Comment: What would be the best option as an outside agent?

Comment: I'm sure there are existing tools made for that, but I've not researched them myself.  There are probably even services that will do it for you. You could, of course, build your own script in a few lines of code that would ping the server and check the output if you had a suitable place to reliably run it from.